# SQL Query to compare fields between Table A and B for duplicate values, and use non-match records in Table B to append to Table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL SERVER.  I have two database tables with 20 fields each, and I need to compare ALL fields in both tables to determine if Table2 has duplicates of records in Table1, and append the non-matching records from Table2 to Table1.

I saw several suggestions, but want the best option to compare both tables and append the non-matching records to Table1.

Please let me know if Option 1 SQL sample below is correct and can do the job, or whether I can use Option 2 also shown below.   My problem with Option 2 is that I am not sure how to use it, and would appreciate some help/suggestions.  Thanks a mil.

Option 1:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET [Num] = A.[Num]
      ,[Desc] = A.[Desc]
      ,[EmpName] = A.[EMPL_NAME]
      ,[EmpNum] = A.[EMPL_NUM]
WHERE(
    SELECT  *   
    FROM Table2 A  
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *      
                      FROM Table1 B
                      WHERE A.[Num] = B.[Num] and
                            A.[Desc] = B.[Desc] and
                            A.[EmpName] = B.[EMPL_NAME] and
                            A.[EmpNum] = B.[EMPL_NUM] and
                      )
             )
```

Option 2:

```
REPLACE INTO Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

This is the current data example:

```
Table1
    Num Desc        EmpName EmpNum
    ------------------------------
    100 aaaaaaaaaaa bbb     null
    200 ccccccccccc ddd     eee
    300 fffffffffff null    kkk

Table2 
    Num Desc        EMPL_NAME EMPL_NUM
    ----------------------------------
    100 aaaaaaaaaaa ccc       ddd
    200 ccccccccccc ddd       eee
    300 ddddddddddd kkk       mmm
    400 nnnnnnnnnnn ppp       www
```

This is the expected result:-

```
Table1 
    Num Desc        EmpName EmpNum
    ------------------------------
    100 aaaaaaaaaaa ccc     ddd
    200 ccccccccccc ddd     eee
    300 ddddddddddd kkk     mmm
    400 nnnnnnnnnnn ppp     www
```

Comment: Append, or Update? "Append" would be add rows that are not there, while "Update" means adjust existing rows with new values... which is what you are doing in your example. (Also, option 2 will not work, as `REPLACE` is a function in SQL server and does not work that way.)

Comment: ...it's probably both, isn't it?

Comment: Hi Philip, thank a mil for your help.  I had an idea but didn't quite know how to accomplish this task, and your explanation helped a lot.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The below operation will delete records from Table1 where the primary key exists in Table2, and then do a full insert of all records in T2 that don't currently exist in T1 by primary key. This will function the same way as updating the rows individually, with the benefit of being set-based and quicker.

```
DELETE a
FROM   table1 a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table2 b
               WHERE  a.num = b.num);

INSERT INTO table1
            (num,
             desc,
             empl_name,
             empl_num)
SELECT num,
       desc,
       empl_name,
       empl_num
FROM   table2 t2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table1 t1
                   WHERE  t1.num = t2.num)
```

Please let me know if there any restrictions that would prevent this solution for your situation.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  However, I don't want to remove any records from Table1 as that is a historical table (sorry I didn't mention this before).  Whatever records are not matching in Table1 I want to take from Table2 and append to Table1.  I will try this solution except I wouldn't delete from Table1 and let you know how the results.

Comment: To answer your question which I didn't, there is no key in the table, so there are no restrictions. I appended the table with the following SQL query and it updated OK as I could quickly verify, i.e. only non-matching records with different Num values. However, in the future there may be several records with matching Num values, but the other fields are different, which we still want to append to the table.  See the SQL sample that I used in next comment window.

Comment: Hi Sast, deleting and inserting the records would accomplish your goal. You said you wanted to append the records; however, in the table1 output your example did not retain any values from table1. If you want to *update* the records, my approach is valid. If you want to *append* your records, you need to update the original question.

Comment: I agree.  I used the wrong SQL example because I was not sure how to do it.  It should be INSERT not UPDATE as shown in the following SQL example I eventually use the get the desired result :                         INSERT INTO table1
            (num,
             desc,
             empl_name,
             empl_num)
SELECT *
FROM   table2 A
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table1 B
                   WHERE A.Num = B.Num and
                A.Desc = B.Desc and
                A.EmpName = B.EMPL_NAME and
                A.EmpNum = B.EMPL_NUM )

Comment: Hi Sast, yeah, this is the same method my answer uses except you're comparing the entire row. At that point, you could even use a `select * from tablea union select * from tableb` which would dedupe - this would be more expensive but if it's a one time thing or whatever, it would work. If you've figured out how you're going to do it, don't forget to indicate your question is answered :)

Comment: Certainly, Sean.  I do appreciate your response.  Sometimes you just need someone to help you figure out exactly how to accomplish a task, and you help was invaluable.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just a quick question, Sean.  How you would use the `select * from tablea union select * from tableb` query in this case.  I tried using it, but it only displayed the union rows.  If I use the INSERT statement with it, the unioned rows are added back to TableA.

Comment: `;with cte as (select * from tableA union select * from tableB) insert into #TempTable; truncate table TableA; insert TableA from #tempTable;` is one route. Another route would be to combine it with a not exists clause, or to do a union all and only insert records that appear once instead of twice (this could be flawed if records on A might not be on B) -- there's a lot of ways to solve this problem, it just depends on how many fields you're comparing and what your goal is.

Comment: Can you send me a more precise example of how to do this with the tables and column names I sent?  Not sure I understand your explanation.

Comment: Hi sast, if you're trying to accomplish this: `However, in the future there may be several records with matching Num values, but the other fields are different, which we still want to append to the table.` I would do something like this: `INSERT INTO Table1 select * from Table2 b where not exists (select 1 from Table1 a where HASHBYTES('md5', lower(concat(a.num, a.desc, a.empl_name, a.empl_num))) = HASHBYTES('md5', lower(concat(b.num, b.desc, b.empl_name, b.empl_num))) );` where the idea is to basically say 'if the row in this exact state in TableB doesn't exist in TableA, insert it.

Comment: Thanks for providing that example.  Is there any reason for using the Lower and Concat functions?

Comment: Hey Sast, the hashbytes function is creating a hash using the md5 algorithm, which is deterministic. The function itself only accepts one argument, so it has to be converted into a data type that can represent all of the values in question before being converted. Concat conveniently adds everything together as a string, returns a varchar, and can be used. The lower() function is used assuming your environment is not case sensitive, as the hashing function IS case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks again for that information.  I have learnt something different today.  While I have resolved to use the INSERT and NOT EXIST method we spoke about before, do you think this method could be used with my 20 column problem?

Comment: Hey Sast, if you have a rowstore and you utilize the hashing method I talked about, in my experience that's been pretty fast - especially if you have a primary key that you can join on. It definitely /can/ work, but it's going to come down to performance on whether or not that's the best approach. Unfortunately, we're way beyond the scope of the question at that point, so I'm not going to make any guesses on that :)

Comment: OK.  Thanks Sean.  Appreciate the information on this.